# MacBook Pro (2014), SD Card for VMWare 7 virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, macbook-pro, sd-card, vmware-fusion

I've been having drive space issues on my MacBook Pro. It's the mid 2014 Retina 13" edition w/120 GB flash drive.
I run VMWare 7 Fusion (for a virtual Windows 8 machine) and my idea is that I buy a 128GB Transcend SD Card and store and run the virtual machine from that.

Has anyone done this before? Any notable issues to watch out for? I've read articles stating that VMWare/Windows can't see the SD Card as a device as it runs via the PCI bus rather than the USB.

Comment: Cons: 1. Will be slow as all hell. 2. I wouldn't trust any mission critical data to an SD card, ever.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the info - so, would the speed be a noticable issue then? I thought the transfer speeds would be adequate. There won't be any mission critical files stored on there. All stored on servers.

Comment: Quick & dirty speed test using Blackmagic - Internal drive, Read 270MB/s Write 258MB/s... ; 32GB SD [formatted GUID/HFS+ as it can't write to NTFS without rebooting] Read 11MB/s Write 6MB/s  [Your SSD drive is likely to be twice as fast as mine, as I'm limited to SATA II]

Comment: Ah I see. The card I'm looking at features Max read: 95 MBps, max write: 60 MBps. This is admitedly best case and still slower than the internal flash drive I know. Hmm....I need to free up space but can't remove any more apps. :-/

Comment: I'd seriously have a look at a bigger SSD. I have 128s in some of the machines here as boot drives, but they all have a stack of big HDs for data storage. My main machine has a 1TB boot drive & I don't know how I'd live without it, now I've got used to the freedom.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's the flash drive in mine which (they say) isn't upgradable although I have seen info to the contrary.

Comment: ah, OK :( Sorry, I'm not really much good on Macbook hardware specifics. Wish you luck though :)